# Generate well behaved trace in "Trace Compass" with python binding

Tags: python, lttng, babeltrace

I'm using babeltrace python binding to crate a trace file from some data I have: The data represent system execution information so there are Tasks being created and run.

I am able to display the trace file in Trace Compass: information pops up in the histogram panel.

I would love to have it displayed properly in the Control Flow panel.

I dumped a trace file taken with lttng and I can see that thread info are inside these tags

```
lttng_statedump_start
lttng_statedump_process_state: { cpu_id = 2 }
lttng_statedump_end
```

Trace Compass does not show these lines, on the other hand "Control flow" panel displays all threads in the system

an example line:

```
 [15:31:49.098426008] (+0.000000858) nostromo lttng_statedump_process_state: { cpu_id = 2 }, { tid = 62, vtid = 62, pid = 62, vpid = 62, ppid = 2, vppid = 2, name = "kcompactd0", type = 1, mode = 5, submode = 0, status = 5, ns_level = 0, ns_inum = 4026531836 }
```

I tried to create a similar stream_class in my python but as you see the cpu_id is empty, and these lines are displayed in Trace compass but nothing pops up in Control Flow panel

```
[01:00:00.000000012] (+0.000000000) 0 lttng_statedump_process_state: { }, { tid = 12, vtid = 25, pid = 57, vpid = 2382432512, ppid = 0, vppid = 0, name = "ciccio", type = 0, mode = 0, submode = 0, status = 0, ns_level = 0, ns_inum = 0 }
```

- How do I set cpu_id?
- Am I on the good path to get this running?

Answer (score 1):

The control flow view requires "sched_switch" operations to be populated. Do you have these events enabled in your trace?

If you're looking for faster feedback by the way, look at the community section of www.tracecompass.org.

Mailing list: tracecompass-dev@eclipse.org

IRC channel: #tracecompass on the OFTC network

[Report a Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tracecompass)